# Something wrong, with my facebook graph URL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-apps

I'm obviously doing something wrong when trying to access information from the facebook graph API, here is the code of my page:

It fetches everything I need other than the users email address, I understand  you need extended permissions which I have requested as seen in my code below.

```
require 'src/facebook.php';
$app_id = "211665122244023";


     $canvas_page = "http://apps.facebook.com/midcitymafia/";

     $auth_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=" 
            . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($canvas_page) . "&scope=email,publish_actions";

     $signed_request = $_REQUEST["signed_request"];

     list($encoded_sig, $payload) = explode('.', $signed_request, 2); 

     $data = json_decode(base64_decode(strtr($payload, '-_', '+/')), true);

$user_id = $data["user_id"];
     if (empty($data["user_id"])) {
            echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $auth_url . "'</script>");
     } else {
                         $graph1 = file_get_contents ("https://graph.facebook.com/".$user_id . "/?accesstoken=" . $data["oauth_token"]);
         $graph=json_decode($graph1,true);
     }



$userid =  $user_id;
$username = $graph['name'];
$usergender = $graph['gender'];
$useremail = $graph['email'];

?>

<br>

<?php echo 'ID: ' . $userid; ?>
<br>
<?php echo 'Name: ' . $username; ?>
<br>
<?php echo 'Gender: ' . $usergender; ?>
<br>
<?php echo 'Email: ' . $useremail; ?>
```

I dumped the $graph variable array to see what information it held, this was the result:

```
array(7) { ["id"]=> string(10) "1469088864" ["name"]=> string(10) "Jack Brown" ["first_name"]=> string(4) "Jack" ["last_name"]=> string(5) "Brown" ["username"]=> string(11) "thebestjack" ["gender"]=> string(4) "male" ["locale"]=> string(5) "en_GB" }
```

It doesn't contain the email address so there is obviously a problem with the access token / using the access token to access the graph.

When I go to my authorised apps on my Facebook account settings under this app it says "this apps needs your email address "blahblah@yahoo.co.uk"

Comment: While your "will to pay a little" is appreciated, it is not going to encourage responses to your question. In fact, it is likely to do the opposite.

Comment: It would help in diagnoses if you edit your question and add the output. Also, check $graph['email'] with isset to see if it actually is null or empty.

Comment: It does say that it outputs all information correctly other than the email and if i manually visit the graph url with token the email address is not displayed..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have a `$_REQUEST["signed_request"]` for any request, doesn't matter if user authorized your app or not. you have it even for users who are not logged in to Facebook at all.

use php-sdk to retrieve user's profile http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/php/facebook-api/

```
<?php
require_once('php-sdk/facebook.php');

$config = array(
  'appId' => '211665122244023',
  'secret' => 'YOUR_APP_SECRET',
);

$facebook = new Facebook($config);
$user_id = $facebook->getUser();
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
    scope => 'email,publish_actions',
    redirect_uri => $canvas_page,));

if($user_id) {
  try {
    $user_profile = $facebook->api('/' . $user_id,'GET');
    $userid =  $user_id;
    $username = $user_profile['name'];
    $usergender = $user_profile['gender'];
    $useremail = $user_profile['email'];

  } catch(FacebookApiException $e) {
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $login_url . "'</script>");
    error_log($e->getType());
    error_log($e->getMessage());
  }   
} else {
    echo("<script> top.location.href='" . $login_url . "'</script>");
}
?>
<?php if (isset($useremail)) : ?>
<br>
<?php echo 'ID: ' . $userid; ?>
<br>
<?php echo 'Name: ' . $username; ?>
<br>
<?php echo 'Gender: ' . $usergender; ?>
<br>
<?php echo 'Email: ' . $useremail; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, WORDS CANNOT EXPLAIN HOW MUCH LOVE I HAVE FOR YOU RIGHT NOW! BEEN STUCK ON THIS FOR LIKE 4/5 DAYS NOW! THANK YOU AGAIN!

Comment: Sorry but to add these details to database would I add the query under the line:
$useremail = $user_profile['email'];
Thanks,
Jack

Comment: short answer - no.
details are here [Facebook Platform Policies](http://goo.gl/2OIr0)

it says: _For all other data obtained through use of the Facebook API, you must obtain explicit consent from the user who provided the data to us before using it for any purpose other than displaying it back to the user on your application._

you do not have this _explicit consent_ at this point, so you can not store it in database.